# Jquery :checked selector returning incorrect count

Tags: jquery, html

I'm a bit puzzled as to why this is happening.

I have used jQuery `:checked` selector from the jQuery API library. The interesting thing here is that I count all radio buttons in a class (pass or fail) and then add them up to show a percentage/count. This works fine once you click through multiple radios but on the first radio button that is selected, it returns 2.

html:

```
<b>
    <input type="radio" name="storeprestidy" value="pass"  class="storepresg" />
    <input type="radio" name="storeprestidy" value="fail" class="storepresp"  /><br />
    <input type="radio" name="storepresclean" value="pass"  class="storepresg" />
    <input type="radio" name="storepresclean" value="fail" class="storepresp"  /><br />
    <input type="radio" name="storepreslights" value="pass"  class="storepresg" />
    <input type="radio" name="storepreslights" value="fail" class="storepresp"  />
</b>
```

javascript:

```
var countChecked = function () {
    var sg = $("input.storepresg:checked").length;
    $("#storepresgtotal").text(sg + (sg === 1));
};
countChecked();
$("input[type=radio]").on("click", countChecked);
```

So if I click on 2 or more of the radio buttons in the class `storepresg`, the count is correct. It's only on the first selection where it is returning an incorrect number (2).

First time poster, hopefully I have presented the question correctly.

Thanks.

Comment: Dunno what you’re asking here. You are only selecting input fields with the class `storepresg` – so only the first of your inputs in the example, because the second one does not have that class – is that on purpose?

Comment: @CBroe, actually when submitting the question the pre/pre code section was greyed out and I though it was going to be omitted. I have multiple values with the same class as storepresg and storepresp. I have only showed one radio button as an example. Please see my updated example.

Comment: Please create a live example on http://jsfiddle.net/ or similar.

Comment: @user3626810, here's the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zdCLm/). What's wrong with it? What's the expected behavior?

Comment: @AymanSafadi actually that fiddle is doing exactly as I described. If you click on the first radio you will see a count of 2. If you click on a second radio it is also 2. If you click on a third, it's 3. The first click should return 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove this:

```
+ (sg === 1)
```

from this:

```
$("#storepresgtotal").text(sg + (sg === 1));
```

Should look like this:

```
$("#storepresgtotal").text(sg);
```

And behave like this: http://jsfiddle.net/zdCLm/1/

Comment: I can't believe it was that simple. Thank you!